# Step by step how to implement Single Sign On with LDAP Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I have Windows authentication with LDAP Active Directory. I have also created a few web sites hosted on my local server. Whenever I go to these websites, these web sites should automatically get logged in based on the Windows credentials and should also provide the facility for other user to log in by simply logging out.

I have tried to get system username and pass to LDAP To get user details by following code.

```
var username = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
```

but that is not the solution I m looking for.

I also read about Kerberos and NTLM but I literally did not get any idea. I have also understood what is SSO means.

I would be happy if any one can give me step by step knowledge regarding how to make SSO work with Windows authentication in intranet applications.

Comment: For windows authentication to automatically log you in, the client machine should be in the same network domain and 'Windows Authentication' enabled in IIS. Is your website consumed outside the server's network domain?

Comment: Yes. any one from anywhere can access the website. If it is accessed from intranet then use 'Windows Authentication' credentials to automatically login otherwise redirect to log in page.

Comment: You can not achieve SSO by using LDAP authentication, even using SPNEGO (Kerberos / Windows integrated authentication) is kind of auto-login and not really SSO. Without a proper knowledge of the underlying technology you will never be able to implement it yourself. A step by step guide won't help as in kind of an error situation you have no chance to solve it yourself.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Actually your assumptions are in correct many organizations structures use LDAP to implement single sing on on a wide ranging of platforms.

Comment: @rogue39nin LDAP is not an SSO technology but can be used for authentication. SSO means provide credentials once, use some kind of 'token' to access multiple applications. How would this be possible using LDAP?